# IOS/Swift: Save the cell selection on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, selection, cell

I have a master detail layout with table views in both of the views. Left panel has a list of patients and right has a list of documents, what happens is by changing the patient selection documents will be reloaded and if the user clicks on a document, it will segue to a webView to display **PDF**.

For consistency purpose i made the first cell in the Patient table to be selected by default using the below code

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);
    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
  }
```

work's fine right?, Yes but it gets a bit inconsistent from here, after closing this PDF document (by clicking done on navigation), my Previously selected cell will go off and it again points to the first Patient. Is there any way to save this selection? Oh and even to save the selection on the details page too. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood your question, but would not storing the indexPath in an instance variable in the delegate `method tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` do the trick?

Comment: @LevLandau can you please see my other comment.

Comment: I see that @Lord Zsolt has already answered your query. I am glad to hear that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `NSIndexPath` property.

Change your viewDidAppear to only default-select the first cell if there wasn't something previously selected:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if (!self.rowToSelect) {
        rowToSelect = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);
        self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
    }    
  }
```

In the `didSelectRow` delegate method store the selected index path in `self.rowToSelect`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, when i tried to assign the indexpath to rottoSelect it pops up an error saying **Cannot assign to 'rowToSelect' in 'self'**. It pops up the same error for both `rowToSelect = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);` and `rowToSelect = indexPath`

Comment: Is it a var or let property? It should be var.

Comment: how can i forget something so simple, Thanks. changing it to var got rid of the error, but now it does not load the data in detail section, because `if ((self.rowToSelect) != nil)` is evaluating to false when the app loads up initially. anyway to get rid of this issue?

Comment: I didnt say != nil, i said == nil. != nil is the same as if (variable) and != nil is the same as if (!variable).

Comment: Works now, Thanks for your help. I accepted and upvoted your answer :)